# Difference between SQS ApproximateAgeOfOldestMessage Average and Maximum?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm creating dashboards for SQS and would like to display the age of the oldest message in the queue.

SQS has the metric `ApproximateAgeOfOldestMessage` and the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-available-cloudwatch-metrics.html) states:

> `ApproximateAgeOfOldestMessage` metric points at the second-oldest message that hasn't been received more than three times

This metric exposes: Average, Minimum, and Maximum.

But in this case wouldn't Average, Minimum and Maximum be equivalent if the metric points at a single message?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what is the difference?

Answer (score 3):

> the metric points at a single message?

Metric don't point at individual messages. They measure the age of messages in a sliding window [period](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_concepts.html#CloudWatchPeriods), e.g. 5 minutes.  Withing this interval you can multiple messages:

> Each **statistic represents an aggregation of the metrics data collected for a specified period of time**. Periods are defined in numbers of seconds, and valid values for period are 1, 5, 10, 30, or any multiple of 60.

Comment: Hmm just confused cause this particular metric says "the second-oldest message that hasn't been received more than three times" - could you give an example how it uses multiple data points?

Comment: Multiple data points are recorded through time. Let's suppose this metric is recorded every minute. Minute 1: 60 seconds. Minute 2: 65 seconds. Minute 3: 55 seconds. Minute 4: 50 seconds. Minute 5: 70 seconds. If you visualize the data with a minute granularity, then minimum, maximum, and average will in fact be the same. But if you change the granularity to 5 minutes, for example, the minimum would be 50, the maximum would be 70, and the average would be 60.